# List all files along with the path in a DBFS folder(Azure Databricks)

Tags: python, scala, databricks, azure-data-lake, azure-databricks

I want to list all the files in dbfs, but I am also getting the last commit to the file appended to the path.

```
import sys, os
import pandas as pd

mylist = []
root = "/dbfs/FileStore/tables"
path = os.path.join(root, "Cleansed") 

for path, subdirs, files in os.walk(path):
    for name in files:
        mylist.append(os.path.join(path, name))


df = pd.DataFrame(mylist)
print(df)
```

Here is the output(the folder has only one file)

```
                                                  0
0  /dbfs/FileStore/tables/Cleansed/processed_file...
1  /dbfs/FileStore/tables/Cleansed/processed_file...
2  /dbfs/FileStore/tables/Cleansed/processed_file...
3  /dbfs/FileStore/tables/Cleansed/processed_file...
4  /dbfs/FileStore/tables/Cleansed/processed_file...
```

**extracting row one

```
print(df[0][1])
```

output

```
/dbfs/FileStore/tables/Cleansed/processed_file.csv/_committed_5302825144935910733
```

Comment: a suggestion is to use a different variable aside for path in ```for path, subdirs, files...```

Comment: if you get `/_committed_....` for every file then you can edit `name` to remove it - ie. `rsplit('/', 1)`. It may gives you the same name many times so you may have to check `if fullname in my_files` before you append. OR you may use `set()` instead of `list()`

Comment: Is that you just want to list csv file?